# unity problem this script dont inherit a native class that can manage a script

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, procedural-generation

Hi im new to both making games and writing code and i use unity and im trying to make procedural generation for a game im making and when i try and attach either my map display or my map generator to a prefab at i get the error this script dont inherit a native class that can manage a script and i have tried looking online for answers and i cant find any so im just going to ask for help here. this is the code for both of the scripts

[image: code for display]

```
using System.Collections;
using UnityEngine;

public class MapGenerator : MonoBehaviour
{
    public int mapWidth;
    public int mapHeight;
    public float noiseScale;

    public void GenerateMap()
    {
        float[,] noiseMap = Noise.GenerateNoiseMap(mapWidth, mapHeight, noiseScale);

        MapDisplay display = FindObjectOfType<MapDisplay>();
        display.DrawNoiseMap (noiseMap);
    }
}
```

Comment: First of all there seems to be missing a closing `}` at the end .. are you getting compiler errors in Unity?

Comment: no compiler errors

Comment: move the file oitside the project, than create a new script from within unity editor and call it MapDisplay, it will create a barebone class with that name that inherits MonoBehaviour. Check if it all compiles and recognize all types, try to add it a sa compoennt on a gameobjest in your scene, then paste all code from your old file, don't forget to close curly braces and check if it all compiles and work.